# ASP.net dynamic checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I generate my check boxes dynamically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtCommon.Count; i++)
{
    CheckBox newBox = new CheckBox();
    newBox.Text = dtCommon[i].userName;
    newBox.CssClass = "cbox";
    if (dtCommon[i].isAlreadyRequired > 0 )
    {
        newBox.CssClass = "cbox highlighted";
        newBox.Checked = true;
    }
    ApprovalSelectPanel.Controls.Add(newBox);
}
```

And when the save button is pressed I call this function:

```
protected void SaveUsers(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

How do I know which check boxes the user has checked?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the `ApprovalSelectPanel.Controls` and cast them back to the corresponding `CheckBox` type and verify the `Checked` property.

Comment: Just be sure that your not regenerating the checkboxes on page_load without checking page.ispostback or you'll get crazy results / errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use CheckBoxList Within the ApprovalSelectPanel instead of add it in the runtime and in the runtime do the following

```
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dtCommon;
        CheckBoxList1.DataMember = "userName";
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

To know which one is selected do the following

```
          foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                //Do any action
            }
```